# Recurrent Neural Network predictions follow shape of test set but shifted down

Tags: recurrent-neural-network

I was wondering if anyone has ever seen something like this. My predictions constantly seem to follow the actual form of the data but always end up shifted down or shifted up. Sometimes it'll seem to be right on as well. Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT: Data is from Amazon stock closing prices on finance.yahoo.com.

[image]

My code is shown below if you'd like to look at it. I have a callback that isn't outlined here since the results occur even when the callback isn't used though it seems to happen more frequently with the callback.

FULL WORKING CODE:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Bidirectional
from keras.layers import SimpleRNN
from keras.layers import Flatten
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.utils import plot_model
from numpy.random import seed

from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

data = pd.read_csv("D:\\AMZN2.csv",header=0,usecols=['Date','Close'],parse_dates=True,index_col='Date')

# Scaled data such that it is centered at 0 with unit variance.
scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaledData = scaler.fit_transform(data)

train = scaledData[:5000]
validation = scaledData[5000:5250]
test = scaledData[5250:]

# Generator Creation #
trainGen = TimeseriesGenerator(data=train,targets=train,length=1,
                              sampling_rate=1,stride=1,
                              shuffle=False,reverse=False,
                              batch_size=8)

valGen = TimeseriesGenerator(data=validation,targets=validation,length=1,
                              sampling_rate=1,stride=1,
                              shuffle=False,reverse=False,
                              batch_size=8)
testGen = TimeseriesGenerator(data=test,targets=test,length=1,
                              sampling_rate=1,stride=1,
                              shuffle=False,reverse=False,
                              batch_size=8) #length 1 batch_size 500

# Designing the Model #
AMZN = Sequential()
AMZN.add(LSTM(32,return_sequences=False,input_shape=(1,1)))
AMZN.add(Dense(1))

# Compiling and training the model #
steps_per_epoch = np.ceil(train.shape[0]/128)
#RMSprop
AMZN.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error',optimizer='adam',metrics=['mae','mse'])
history = AMZN.fit_generator(trainGen,validation_data=valGen,#steps_per_epoch = steps_per_epoch,
                   epochs=20,verbose = 1)

# Predicting and undoing the scaling #
predictions = AMZN.predict_generator(testGen)
predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(predictions)
test = scaler.inverse_transform(test)

# Plotting the Prediction and Test #
plt.plot(predictions,'--',label='Predictions')
plt.plot(test,label='Actual')
plt.xlabel("Observation")
plt.ylabel("Price")
plt.title("AMZN Stock Prediction Vs. Actual")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

EDIT EDIT EDIT:

---

```
predict = np.zeros(len(test)+1)
predict[0] = AMZN.predict(np.asarray([[train[-1]]]))

for i in range(len(test)):
    predict[i+1] = AMZN.predict(test[i].reshape(1,1,1))
    predict[i] = scaler.inverse_transform(predict[i].reshape(1,1))
```

TRAINING RESULTS OF THIS MANUAL METHOD (The steep drop is because I used np.zeros with one extra zero):

---

[image]

EDIT:

Based on how I ran my predictions, I would say length is the number of variables in the input space used to forecast. This is because when I designate a length of 3 I need to provide the model.predict function 3 values.

Comment: I'll try to help if you give a working example.

Comment: You mean full code? One sec.

Comment: OK. I included full working code that makes the result occur. Let me know what you think and thank you!

Comment: At first look I see too precise similarity between the actual and predicted data even if I set epocs=1. That means that there is fundamental logical error in the program, since stock prices are not predictable. I'll try to find the error.

Comment: So I tried just manually controlling everything. I think there's something I'm not grasping with the test generators that might be causing the issues. I'll add an edit to my original post to show how I manually made forecasts one step ahead. The result is a bit more believable I think.

Comment: Nevermind. I tested again and got similar results in the instance where I train the model on the first 5000 observations and test on the remaining observations. I'll add the image of the training.

Comment: Now I had little time again to look at it. One problem is, that you compare the value predicted for tomorrow with the actual value for today. Second problem is, that the history (length) you set to 1. That means that the network cannot find trend. It always will answer such questions: today the price is 1687.987, what will be the price tomorrow? I'll write this as an answer for longer explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to teach the `LSTM` with random data, you will see similar behaviour.
This short code will produce random data in similar form to the stock price you have used:

```
data = random(5528)-0.5
data[0]=1456
for i in range(1,len(data)):
    data[i]+=data[i-1]
data.resize((5528,1))
```

With your code it will produce to following pic.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/weXXz.png
As you can see, the behaviour is very similar with random data.

You have used length=1 , that means to predict for tomorrow it will use price of today. The predictions will contain one less item than test.

```
In [31]: len(test)
Out[31]: 278

In [32]: len(predictions)
Out[32]: 267
```

So the first you should correct is the plotting:

```
plt.plot(predictions,'--',label='Predictions')
plt.plot(test[1:],label='Actual')
```

With that change you will compare the price of tomorrow with the price predicted for tomorrow.

The second problem is that 1 value is simply nothing to forecast from.
You cannot say much more than that probably tomorrow will be the same price.

The third thing is not a problem, it is OK, that the network will learn a shift upwards or downwards.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been having such a difficult time grasping these models due to the shifts. I kept seeing how they were shifted over and was misunderstanding what was happening. I didn't realize that I was plotting the full test set against a prediction set that was shifted by length.

Comment: I changed my model and will begin working with different values for length. Thank you again stranger!

Comment: You are welcome. I hope you are few steps forward with this help. Keep in mind that it is practically not possible to predict stock prices in that way. If you make lot of tests you will find that.

Comment: Yes I'm certainly aware of that fact. This was moreso a project to practice with these neural networks on a simple dataset. I agree 100% that this isn't a feasible method.

Comment: Actually, I just thought of a question. In the Keras documentation it states that length corresponds to the length of the output sequence. Isn't length therefore determining how far out we're forecasting? If not then how is that determined? I was thinking it might be batch_size since I know we're inputting our data in 3D and one dimension is the batch size.

Comment: Good question. I will check.

Comment: Here is the documentation on TimeseriesGenerator: https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/

Comment: Hmmmm.... you are right, the doc says this. However you have input shape parameter, where you can set the history and no output shape. I guess you set history with the length parameter. I have not yet seen the source code for that.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure the source code is accessible. I tried using inspect but it just gives a description. Here is the Github repo: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/preprocessing/sequence.py